# Migrating SBS 2003 to 2011, and hangs when migrating Public Folders

Tags: exchange-2003, migration, windows-sbs-2003, windows-sbs-2011

I've been following the migration guide at http://www.it-book.co.uk/1651/migration-from-sbs-2003-to-sbs-2011-3.

The option "Migrate Exchange mailbox and settings" links me to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg563803.aspx

When I get to the stage of right-clicking "Move All Replicas", it instantly hangs.

I can't see anything specifically in the event viewer at the time this happens.

Is this a case of waiting, or is there something more going on here?

[image: Move All Replicas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the size of the public folders, and the Exchange information store. 2k3 has soft and hard limits regarding size.

Also run the task manager, and see if there is any bottle necks in the system, not enough ram, too much disk i/o etc.

Comment: Looks like pub1.edb is 1.2GB and pub1.stm is 3GB.  Cpu is around 50%, memory is high, using 3.5GB of page file, but shouldn't be too of an issue.

Comment: Have noticed that when I browse to Administrative Groups > First administrative group > Folder > Public Folders, it also hangs.  Will see if it has shown anything by morning.